# Unable to find the registered languages while saving the file

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Steps to Reproduce:

1.Create a new sample project by selecting New Language support.

2.Now add the following code in package.json to register 3 new languages.

```
        "languages": [
            {
            "id": "db2_z",
            "aliases": ["Db2Z"],
            "extensions": [".spsql", ".sql",".z"],
            "configuration": "./language-configuration.json"
            },
            {
            "id": "db2_i",
            "aliases": ["Db2i"],
            "extensions": [".spsql", ".sql",".i"],
            "configuration": "./language-configuration.json"
            },
            {
                "id": "db2_luw",
                "aliases": ["Db2Luw"],
                "extensions": [".spsql", ".sql",".luw"],
                "configuration": "./language-configuration.json"
            }
        ]
```

3.Now when I run the extension it displays only one language type while saving. But while selecting the language mode it shows three languages.

Please check the attached screenshots.

[image: Here you can find the 3 languages.]

[image: But while saving we can see only one language.]

But while saving we can see only one language.

I tried all the things but unable to figure out the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[According to language overview](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview)

*"You can add new file extensions to an existing language with the files.associations setting."*

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.php4": "php",
    "*.php5": "php"
}
```

```
"files.associations": {
    "**/somefolder/*.*": "php"
}
```